# Inserting an AST into a quote do end block without unquoting it

Tags: metaprogramming, elixir

Using `quote do end` with `unquote` normally provides a super easy way to inject values into an AST, allowing me to avoid traversing it.

Here is one such situation.

```
ast = quote do 1 + 1 end
quote do
  unquote(ast)
  |> manipulate_number
end
```

However, if I want to insert not the result of the quoted expression `1 + 1`, but the AST `{:+, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [1, 1]}`, I find myself wrapping the AST in the AST of another call to `quote do end`, like so:

```
ast1 = quote do 1 + 1 end
ast2 = {:quote, [], [[do: ast1]]}
quote do
  unquote(ast2)
  |> manipulate_number
end
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to inject the AST as is into another quoted expression, you want `Macro.escape/1`. Another way to put it, you can use `Macro.escape/1` to ensure some quoted expression will return itself when evaluated/expanded.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following should do what you desire:

```
defmodule MacroExample do
  defmacro example(ast) do
    quoted = quote bind_quoted: [ast: ast] do
      ast + 3
    end
    IO.inspect Macro.to_string(quoted)
    quoted
  end
end

defmodule MacroTest do
  require MacroExample
  IO.inspect MacroExample.example(1 + 1)
end
```

And the result in `iex`:

```
iex> c "test.ex"
"(\n  ast = 1 + 1\n  ast + 3\n)"
5
```

I'm guessing that your specific problem is likely more complicated than just deferring the addition operation though, if the above isn't what you are looking for, perhaps a more realistic example of what you are trying to accomplish could clarify the problem and it's solution.